# xdebug configure showing wrong version of php

Tags: php, centos, xdebug

I need to configure xdebug directory on centos 6.

When I run ./configure in xdebug to prepare my make file I get:

```
configure: error: not supported. Need a PHP version >= 7.0.0 and < 7.4.0 (found 5.6.30)
```

however

```
php -v
```

gives me:

```
PHP 7.1.30 (cli) (built: Jul 23 2019 18:46:30) ( NTS )
```

wtf

However, after poking around a bit I see that centos comes with a package called php-devel that defaults to 5.6. Could this be the issue? If so how do I resolve it? yum search gave me this package: ea-php71-php-devel.x86_64 but it is already installed I guess...

output of which php:

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

and which phpize

```
/usr/local/bin/phpize
```

phpize give the output:

```
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
```

which should be:

```
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   20160303
```

And I notice that running

```
php-config --version
```

gives me: 5.6.30

Thats probably the issue but how do I fix it? I looked at [xdebug faqs](https://xdebug.org/docs/faq) and saw: "If it doesn't match up, and perhaps the wrong "phpize" binary is found on the path, you can run configure as follows":

```
/full/path/to/php/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/full/path/to/php/bin/php-config
```

But I dont understand that.... /full/path/to/php/bin/phpize is the path to the binary isn't it - how can you configure that then?

Comment: What's the output of "which php" and "which phpize" ? You should make sure you're running phpize from the directory containing your PHP 7 binaries before running configure.

Comment: I have added that. they are the same directory

Comment: What was the phpize output?

Comment: Added that and more info to question

Comment: It sounds like you might have two php-devel packages overlapping. Maybe you had 5.6 installed by default, then you installed 7.1 without removing 5.6, then the next package update overwrote 7.1 back to 5.6. Make sure you don't have conflicting packages installed for PHP.

Comment: @jhilgeman I'm not sure I have it at all which php-devel give me nothing

Comment: show `yum list installed | grep php-devel`

Comment: @FAEWZX - that outputs: ea-php71-php-devel.x86_64 7.1.30-4.4.1.cpanel so I guess that is not the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path to cpanel php-devel bin

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php__VERSION__/root/usr/bin/
```

For package ea-php71-php-devel.x86_64 7.1.30-4.4.1.cpanel

```
cd /full/path/to/module/xdebug
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/phpize && ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php-config
```

Comment: Awesome! that was it!